# Jersey JAXB Marshalling sets default namespace to ns4 even though package-info.java is defined otherwise

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have an Jersey API that returns Odata standard responses and consumes the same. There are specific name spaces necessary for these responses. I have a package-info.java class:

```
@XmlSchema(
xmlns = {
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = ""),
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices", prefix = "d"),
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata", prefix = "m")
},
namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package my.package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

I use JAXB to automatically marshal and unmarshal the incoming request body and outgoing response for me. I have beans annotated for these purposes. Here is an example of one:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
public class Entry
{
private String id;
private String title;
private Date updated;
private AtomLink link;
private Content content;

public Entry()
{
}

public Entry(final Content content)
{
this.content = content;
}

public Entry(final String id, final String title, final Date updated, final AtomLink link, final Content content)
{
this.id = id;
this.title = title;
this.updated = updated;
this.link = link;
this.content = content;
}

@XmlElement(name = "title")
public String getTitle()
{
return title;
}

public void setTitle(final String title)
{
this.title = title;
}

@XmlElement(name = "link")
public AtomLink getLink()
{
return link;
}

public void setLink(final AtomLink link)
{
this.link = link;
}

@XmlElement(name = "id")
public String getId()
{
return id;
}

public void setId(final String id)
{
this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "updated")
public Date getUpdated()
{
return updated;
}

public void setUpdated(final Date updated)
{
this.updated = updated;
}

@XmlElement(name = "content")
public Content getContent()
{
return content;
}

public void setContent(final Content content)
{
this.content = content;
}
}
```

The response comes across like this.

```
<ns4:entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ns4:id>TEwxaTFL</ns4:id>
<ns4:title>my resource</ns4:title>
<ns4:link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/API/resource(TEwxaTFL)" rel="self"/>
<ns4:content type="application/xml"> 
    <m:properties>
        <d:name>temp_170_ruleset</d:name>
        <d:shared>false</d:shared>
        <d:autorun>false</d:autorun>
    </m:properties>
</ns4:content>
</ns4:entry>
```

As you can see the other namespaces come across just fine. The default name space is coming back with a ns4 prefix rather than no prefix. I need it to be like this:

```
    <entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>TEwxaTFL</id>
<title>my resource</title>
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/API/resource(TEwxaTFL)" rel="self"/>
<content type="application/xml"> 
    <m:properties>
        <d:name>temp_170_ruleset</d:name>
        <d:shared>false</d:shared>
        <d:autorun>false</d:autorun>
    </m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

I've tried altering the package-info.java class to remove the name spaces:
removing

```
@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = ""),
```

and

```
namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
```

and removing one at a time. Doing these things never fix the namespace prefix but affected how posts happened - mapping was not possible.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here? I really don't want to "manually" marshal every response. So I want to avoid a NamespacePrefixMapper solution, unless I can define that without manually marshaling the response. I've read where this is suppose to work.

I use Jersey 1.12, JAXB 2.2

--Outcome--
Using Moxy works. I was struggling with getting it to work because the imports used were still the JaxB that was not working for me. Syntactically using Moxy is the same so there was no overhead of updating code for us. We simply needed to add the jaxb.properties file and update our imports. The only other way we got rid of the default namespaces being like this (ns1, ns4, etc.) was to use XSL on the way out - and that sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) expert group.

**package-info**

Using the following `package-info` with MOXy as the JAXB provider I was able to produce the XML that you are looking for.  The line that is commented out is necessary until we finish the fix for the following bug:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/365457

```
@XmlSchema(
xmlns = {
    //@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = ""),
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices", prefix = "d"),
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata", prefix = "m")
},
namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package forum9795350;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: I saw MOXy as an alternative in my research to a fix. At this point I'm willing to give it a shot. From my research it doesn't seem like anymore configuration, except for the properties file in the package of the beans I'm transforming. It looks like I'll have to put a properties file in each package that has the beans I want to transform. Unless there is a way to put one in a more parent package. Anyway, will this work, or will I need to manually load it? `<dependency><groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId><artifactId>jersey-moxy</artifactId><version>1.12</version></dependency>`

Comment: @user1053116 - You will need to add the jaxb.properties file in atleast one of the packages that the `JAXBContext` is created on.  If you have any problems let me know and I'll help you out:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html

Comment: There's no form showing up at that site. I added MOXy - works nice. Except for one thing, and I'm not having any luck fixing. The only thing I added was the jaxb.properties file. The XML comes across without any namespace prefix, but it's including the colon. So the XML output is like this `<:entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
xmlns:="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<:id>TEwxaTFL</:id>` - not sure how to get rid of the colon.

Comment: @Elrond - Which version of EclipseLink MOXy are you using?  The latest is 2.3.2:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Comment: I was using the jersey contribution. I'll get the latest `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: With 2.3.2 - I get ns0 as the default namespace prefix. And nested beans are having a different namespace prefix than the one defined in the XMLElement annotation -  `xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"`. For example, under the autorun property I have another bean defined - Account. But, that property has the XMLElement annotation with the namespace being the "d", which is mapped to the one with the prefix ns1. Maybe it's how my beans are annotated?

Comment: @Elrond - Did you remove the following line from your package-info?  `@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = "")`

Comment: I did - it didn't make a difference. `@XmlSchema(
 xmlns = {
  @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices", prefix = "d"),
  @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata", prefix = "m")
    },
 namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
 elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
 attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package com.mine.api.ruleset;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;`

Comment: Could you send me a message through my contact page (http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html)?  I'll send you the example I have.

Comment: @Elrond - That plugin appears to be down at the moment, there is also a "Contact Me" link on my home page:  http://www.bdoughan.com.